# Internet Explorer 9-11 does not fill g element with color (highcharts)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, highcharts

Using, highcharts I'm trying to get the fill color to work properly on IE.  In the picture below, you'll see the background is transparent (no color at all).  I need it to be black with an opacity of 0.8.

Changing the `fill` css property in Firefox/Chrome will change the color.

What do I need to do to get the fill property to show up?

Example Markup:

```
<g class="highcharts-tooltip" zIndex="8" style="cursor:default;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;" visibility="hidden" opacity="0" transform="translate(295,43)">
   <rect rx="3" ry="3" fill="none" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="92" height="46.046875" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(1, 1)"></rect>
   <rect rx="3" ry="3" fill="none" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="92" height="46.046875" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(1, 1)"></rect>
   <rect rx="3" ry="3" fill="none" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="92" height="46.046875" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.15" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(1, 1)"></rect>
   <rect rx="3" ry="3" fill="0.5" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="92" height="46.046875" stroke="#e87c05" stroke-width="1" anchorX="104.5" anchorY="31"></rect>
   <text x="8" y="21" style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#ffffff;fill:#ffffff;" zIndex="1">
      <tspan style="fill:#acacac" x="8">Excellent</tspan>
      <tspan style="font-weight:bold" x="8" dy="16">91</tspan>
      <tspan dx="0"> Responses</tspan>
   </text>
</g>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was staring me right in the face.  The `<rect>` elements have a fill of none.  Change those, and it works as expected.